# How to serialize list of polymorphic objects using built_value and StandardJsonPlugin?

Tags: dart

Given a class hierarchy of animals like in the [built_value polymorphism example](https://github.com/google/built_value.dart/blob/0f131d8cedb271405a52652f9b5eaa61c2c589aa/example/lib/polymorphism.dart):

```
Animal
    - Cat
    - Fish
```

I want to be able to (de)serialize a list of animals to JSON

```
class Zoo implements Built<Zoo, ZooBuilder>  {
    static Serializer<Zoo> get serializer => _$zooSerializer;
    BuiltList<Animal> animals;
}
```

I would like the type of animal to be encoded in each item. For example the json output could look like:

```
{
"animals": [
    {"type": "cat", "legs": 2},
    {"type": "fish", "fins": 3}
]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: this question/answer are now out of date; StandardJsonPlugin now supports polymorphism out of the box, as of version 4.5.0.

StandardJsonPlugin does not currently support polymorphism. According to the docs:

```
/// The default serialization format is more powerful, supporting polymorphism
/// and more collection types.
```

This issue, "Swagger / OpenAPI support", includes adding polymorphism support to StandardJsonPlugin:

https://github.com/google/built_value.dart/issues/92

One question: why do you need StandardJsonPlugin in the first place? If you stop using it, you have polymorphism support :)

Comment: I want to use StandardJsonPlugin so that I have a map I can save to a document database on the server side. For example so I can create indexes on the data in the database. As I understand it, using the default serializer only gives me a list of objects.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. It would be good to investigate the possibilities with someone who has an actual use case ... if you have a github account could you please file an issue at https://github.com/google/built_value.dart/issues ?